# Haskell about matching a Char with a list

Tags: list, haskell, match

I am looking for a way that when input a `Char`, then the function could match the list, like `"QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOPL"`, and then return the index of the matching one

For example, when input `'S'`, then it could find the `'S'` is the 5th element in the list then return integer `4` (starting with `0`).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the function `elemIndex` from `Data.List`:

```
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int

-- Example
main = do
    let i = elemIndex 'S' "QZAXSWED"
    case i of
        Just idx -> print idx
        Nothing  -> putStrLn "'S' not found in list"
```

There's also the function `elemIndices` that returns all the indices of an element in a list, but it's going to take longer to run since it has to scan the entire list every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Prelude Data.List> elemIndex 'S' "QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOPL"
Just 4
```